# How to keep HtmlHelper from escaping URL parts

Tags: javascript, templates, cakephp

Using CakePHP 2.2, I would like to generate the following link in a view:

```
<a href="/teams/edit/${$data.Team.id}">Edit</a>
```

This markup is later picked up by a Javascript templating engine, hence the `${$data.Team.id}` part.

This was my obvious first attempt:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Edit',
    array('controller' => 'teams', 'action'=>'edit', '${$data.Team.id}')
);
```

The result:

```
<a href="/teams/edit/%24%7B%24data.Team.id%7D">Edit</a>
```

`$`, `{`, and `}` are nicely URL encoded - which I don't want.

OK, but there's an `'escape' => false` option, says [The Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3alink).

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Edit',
    array('controller' => 'teams', 'action'=>'edit', '${$data.Team.id}'),
    array('escape' => false)
);
```

The result doesn't change. Apparently, the `'escape'` param only influences the handling of actual query strings, in the `'?'` key of the URL array.

How can I achieve the desired result using the HtmlHelper?

Comment: It is not valid to have those characters unescaped in the path name.

Comment: This isn't cake, your browser is encoding those characters. paste `<a href="/teams/edit/${$data.Team.id}">Edit</a>`; the result is the same. could you use `data-` attributes?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: as I've written: the markup goes through further processing by Javascript before it is inserted into the DOM as an actual link. These characters are placeholders and will be replaced.

Comment: @pixelistik doesn't really matter. It is a browser mechanic as Ross said. Once the URL is parsed into the DOM as an `href` property of an anchor element, it will be forced through encoding.

Comment: @Ross: it definitely is the HtmlHelper. When I directly paste the desired markup, the characters stay as they are.

Comment: Though, JS template engines should parse the page as pure text so I see your point. Though this is still not a valid to place those unescaped characters in the anchor's href if it reaches the client as HTML.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: The template is "hidden" from browser parsing in a `<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">` tag. This is a common technique for Javascript templates. jQuery Template later parses this template - and replaces the placeholders.

Comment: Yes, I updated the last comment. Though I'm not sure whether cake provides a method for that. When you view the source, is it unescaped? If so, try adding a CDATA block surrounding your `text/x-jquery-tmpl` script content to ensure that it isn't parsed as HTML.

Comment: This is not a browser parsing thing. "View source" already shows it, as well as loading the page without any browser (using `curl`).

Comment: So you're using [jQuery.tmpl](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl) or some other templating engine? Theoretically you shouldn't run into issues as long as it is parsed as text then.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with named parameter array `/controller/index/named[key]:2` gets changed to `/controller/index/named%5Bkey%5D:2`. Did you have a reasonable solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve what you want. The Router will urlencode all named and passed params. You can use `HtmlHelper::url()` to generate the `/teams/edit/` part and then use simple string concatination.

Edit: You could probably use a custom RouteClass and overwrite the CakeRoute::_writeUrl() method which does the encoding. Pass a special param in the url array to tell it to not encode and that unset that param.

Comment: Thanks for a clear "no". Your suggestion for a workaround is also nice, I'll do it like that. It's just about 1-2 links in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own helper for this and not using the link helper. In my helper, I used the url helper to generate the base url, then I appended my desired parameters.